# Google Analytics URL builder to track campaigns

Tags: url, google-analytics

I have URL built using URL Builder for analysis tracking on Google Analytics :

```
https://cdnresources.s3.amazonaws.com/splash_images/uid_3429_1455443361903coke-free_with_mcpizza.jpg?utm_source=Tofa7teen%20%20Cafe&utm_medium=Splash%20Page&utm_term=PoP-Ads&utm_content=ads%20on%20tofa7teen&utm_campaign=Tofa7teen%20Campaign%20
```

and the main domain is different from the main in this URL , in another way

how to track different links from orignal website URL in Google Analytics ?

Answer (score 2):

The utm parameters would only be sent to your Analytics account if it was followed from an external link to a page on your domain which has your tracking code on it. It would then match the utm parameters from the link leading to your site with the other attributes collected for that user's session.

If this image is to be used as an outbound link you can track it [using a click event:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#outbound_link_and_form_tracking)

```
function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href
  });
}
```

Then by setting an onclick='handleOutBoundLinkClicks(e)' attribute to these outbound link images.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply , but in my case the image is not clickable and i don't have it's code , i have subscribed to cloud platform x that pop-up this image as an pop-up ad , the only option that i can control it , is to change the url of this image as i mentioned it before, so how to track it ,? I hope my case in clear now...